# Convert using LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I write this code to subtract binary values , I need instead of for loop using, I need to use LINQ for performance issue , I tried but  Ifailed, the code is

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] data = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };

            if (data[0] == 1)
            {

                byte[] One = new byte[data.Length];
                One[One.Length - 1] = 1;

                byte borrow = 0; 

                for (int i= data.Length -1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
                {
                    if(borrow == 1 ) data[i] = 0; 
                    if (data[i] == 0 && One[i] == 0)
                    {
                        borrow = 0; data[i] = 0;

                    }
                    else if (data[i] == 0 && One[i] == 1)
                    {
                        borrow = 1 ; data[i] = 1;

                    }
                    else if (data[i] == 1 && One[i] ==0)
                    {
                        borrow = 0; data[i] = 1;

                    }
                    else if (data[i] == 1 && One[i] == 1)
                    {
                        borrow = 0; data[i] = 0;

                    }
                    if (data[i] == 1) data[i] = 0; else data[i] = 1;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ internally also uses loops, why do you think it will give you a performance benefit?

Comment: Linq would not give you better performance

Comment: What is it subtracting from data? And if performance is an issue, why not convert to ints to do the subtraction?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I heard adn read about LINQ high performance, is this true

Comment: Please provide the source for this. I don't know what you read, but there is no way a LINQ statement is a lot faster than an equivalent loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq doesn't add any beneficiary to your sample code, It just make it little slower, because of some internally function calls, it just implements yield pattern in some cases, but your code doesn't need this, Also with linq it's more complicated, but your current code is easy to read. So I suggest do not use linq, except it make your life better. not doing everything with linq.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert your binary number to an integer type, e.g.

```
Int32 x = Convert.ToInt32("100000100100", 2);

/* Perform your arithmetic here */

string result = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
```

I'm not sure how that is for performance, but I would assume it's faster than any solution involving LINQ.

Comment: I need to work on the binary firsst, and select certain part and pad the others with zero then convert